# PHPMyadmin: Every click redirects to login page

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed a phpmyadmin also with the default configuration and created it's own virtual host on port 49251. Everything is working fine except that after successfully logging inside the phpmyadmin, any clicks to any link would take me to the login page. It will continue doing the same thing when you continue to put the username/passwd everytime, which is a pain when you need to do something important.

I can only find this error in mysql

```
2019-02-27T08:31:10.641198Z 286105 [Note] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you are using a blank user id. You may need to check the setup of phpadmin and what you have entered for the user name.

Comment: @SloanThrasher which config specifically ? the php is configured to use memcache as session handler but every config is set to the default ones

Comment: Specifically, the user Id to sign into the database. Look at the log entry in your question. ```Access denied for user ''@'localhost'``` See the empty quotes before the @, that's the user id to sign into the database.

Comment: @SloanThrasher where can I debug it in phpmyadmin files ?